# Google Chrome Inspector: How to edit an Object on a break point?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Didn't see a duplicate of this question.

I have a break point on an event object (from fullCalendar). I'd like to change a parameter manually since this data is coming from a backend.

e.g.

```
event: Object
 start: Fri Dec 14 2012 13:30:00 GMT-0600
```

to

```
event: Object
 start: Fri Dec 14 2012 17:30:00 GMT-0600
```

Not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that when script execution is paused, the scope variables (A.K.A local variables and closure variables) become available in the console! You should be able to modify them from there

Disclaimer:
I'm using Chromium 22 and I don't know if this is a bug in Chrome or the desired behaviour

Comment: Man it's been a long day haha. That worked! was able to set it using event.start = "Fri Dec 14 2012 17:30:00 GMT-0600 (CST)" in console. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of service. It's a weird quirk that I found by accident.